# Persisting controller data while switching views in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular with UI-router and whenever I switch to a different view and then return back to the original, the controller is re instantiated.

I know that I can save the state via a service and to repopulate it afterwards, but is there some sort of option in ui-router that allows me to not reinitialize the controller?

Comment: Use service to sharing data angular your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one controller for multiple views then  you can uses the nested state feature of ui-router to keep track of states. See the documentation [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)